# Which one is more performant : using Swift Array.contains function OR checking with if (.. || .. || .. )?

Tags: swift, performance

In our Swift code we're often writing this when we want to check if `foo` is a particular value :

`if [kConstantOne, kConstant2, kConstant3].contains(foo) {...}`

I was wondering how this compared, performance wise, to a normal `if` statement where you compare the values with `||`.

`if kConstantOne == foo || kConstant2 == foo || kConstant3 == foo {...}`

Does the compiler optimises this statement or is an array effectively allocated, instantiated and looped to check for equality?

It's an easier, a bit more fancy way to write these simple `if` statements, but if there would be a significant performance impact, which I seriously doubt it will, we should try to avoid it.

EDIT : A single isolated use of this would not have any impact, but I'm more interested to know what happens when it would be part of a larger algorithm. What happens when your code is hitting this statement or other similar ones a few thousand times, allocating and initialising an array and using the contains function for equality checking.

Comment: Are you experiencing a performance impact? If not, isn't this a case of premature optimization? Or even of idle speculation? How much difference do you suppose this might make _really_?

Comment: @matt We're not experiencing a performance impact. I was wondering if this could potentially be a performance hit when this smaller piece of logic is executed more often as part of another larger process. Let's hypothetically say this happens in some sort of parsing logic where you come across this 1000 times. Could the creation of an array and looping over the values be a potential problem? I'll put this in the original answer too.

Comment: "Let's hypothetically say this happens in some sort of parsing logic where you come across this 1000 times. Could the creation of an array and looping over the values be a potential problem" The only question of interest is whether it's an _actual_ problem. Try it and see.

Comment: I have seen far too many cases of someone trying to cleverly avoid a performance problem, and in the process make things slower. You can only do performance work by testing actual implementations very carefully. If this is only called 1000 times, its hard to imagine how it would matter one way or the other anyway. That's a tiny number of iterations for the kind of difference you'd expect here.

Comment: Ok, I did some tests in a playground and came to the conclusion that relatively to each other the method with the creation of the array is around 4 times slower than the other one. Looking at total time elapsed.. it will never be an issue, unless we're talking about enormous amounts of data.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to explore this further, but note that performance testing in a playground is completely meaningless. Not only is it not optimized (which causes massive performance changes in Swift), but the time required to generate the debug strings that show up in the right-hand column will generally dwarf the timings of the thing under test. Performance testing is very challenging, especially micro-benchmarks of isolated code. It is very common to accidentally benchmark your test system rather than the system under test.

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about the performance impact, the *only* way to explore this is to benchmark it in code that you believe would cause the performance impact. While we can do some reasoning about current compiler implementation details, this is no way to translate those into answering questions of "significant performance impact" and in many cases your intuition will be wrong (`map` is very slightly faster than a simple `for` loop in most cases, which is counter-intuitive until you read the implementation of `map`; but it's a very tiny difference).

Write the code clearly to say what you mean. The first does that.

It is possible that the `if` statement is very slightly faster than the `contains` and allows some compiler optimizations (that may or may not actually occur) that `contains` does not. It definitely does not create a temporary array or anything like that. However, this is going to be nearly unmeasurable over such a tiny array either way. If this is part of an inner loop that is called a few tens of millions of times, I have some approaches I would explore to optimize it (which wouldn't look like either of these; I'd focus first on getting rid of the `==` if these aren't integers). If this is called fewer than a million times, then you're more likely to accidentally hurt performance than help it by micro-optimizing like this. You're definitely likely to hurt maintainability.